# List of `NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE` API's?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been looking at a variety of Application Extension ideas, both the extension point and what API's I'd like to integrate.

The older legacy docs in the archive are actually still pretty heavily linked by the modern Apple docs, and it says:

> Use any API marked in header files with the NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE macro, or similar unavailability macro, or any API in an unavailable framework  [<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2)

Searching, I saw some conversations about how Swift's `available` attribute, and the argument `iOSApplicationExtension` might be the replacement.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/attributes/#available

---

Can someone comment/clarify?
Also, if this is true, is there some way of asking Xcode to tell me what API's are `iOSApplicationExtension` ?